# Using E(fx)clipse and getting error with JRE

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, efxclipse

I currently am trying to work with JavaFX and my teach recommended we work with e(fx)clipse. I uploaded this plug in to my typical eclipse application, but every time I try and create a new project, I get an error that my JRE files cannot be detected. I have tried building a new path and configuring my JRE, but nothing is working. It just says JRE(unbound).

EDIT: I am creating a new JavaFX project

[image: This is what my workspace looks like when I try and build path]

Does anyone have any idea as to why this is occurring and have any way to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your build path is using an 'Execution Environment' which has not been bound to an actual JRE.

Open the Preferences and go to the 'Java > Installed JREs > Execution Environments' page. Select the 'JavaSE-10' entry and select a suitable JRE.

If there are no suitable JREs for JavaSE-10 you will need to go to the 'Java > Installed JREs' page and Add a Java 10 JRE.